# Finding Wigner function of four maximal entangled Bell state

Tags: entanglement, density-matrix, wigner-function

How can we find a Wigner function for the four maximally entangled Bell states $(|00\rangle  \pm |11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, $(|01\rangle \pm |10\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$?

I have used the basis where labels for each qubit are $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z$ eigenvalues. The thing is that I have first expressed the two-qubit density matrix in terms of tensor product of Pauli matrices however I am not able to proceed how to proceed further.

Comment: what's your definition of Wigner function here? It is most commonly introduced in contexts  where you have a continuous wavefunction, i.e. for CV systems, which doesn't seem to be the case here. Or are these "Bell states" excitation states of some many-boson system? Granted, discrete Wigner functions do exist, but it would be good for you to clarify which definition you are using

Comment: "The" discrete Wigner function for qubits does not really deserve its name as it lacks important properties of both the discrete WF of higher-dimensional systems and the CV WF. That's why noone is really using it in the qubit case. That being said, you can certainly compute the WF, e.g. by computing the (symplectic) Fourier transform of the coefficients in the Pauli basis (this is Gross's definition).

Comment: @glS Here the WIgner function is going to be a $4 \times 4$ matrix. So basically I have to find a $4 \times 4$ matrix