# Evaluation of Wigner function representation of a Bloch Sphere

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, bloch-sphere, wigner-function

Consider Wigner function representation of a qubit in the basis labeled by $\sigma_z$ and $\sigma_x$ eigenvalues. A general single qubit mixed state has the Bloch representation,$\rho = 1/2 (I + r.\sigma)$with $|r| ≤ 1$. Find the region of the Bloch sphere such that each element of its Wigner function is positive.

In this problem how can we evaluate the wigner function as we know that wigner function is one of the density matrices?

Comment: @gIS thanks for comment

Comment: what's your definition of "Wigner function" here? That's the same question I asked in [this other related question of yours](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21853/55), but "it is going to be a 4x4 matrix" is not a definition. Do you know what "Wigner function" means in this context?

Comment: The "Wigner function" for spin states is not unique. For example, you can have [continuous](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.24.2889) and [discrete](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.53.2998) representations (the list goes on). The Husimi $Q$-function is unique, so that could be helpful